Argument for non-existence of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$
I have a couple of questions about this answer by Noam D. Elkies showing that there exist no elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$ having nonconstant $j_E$-invariant.
The strategy is to consider
$G:={\rm Gal}\bigl(\overline{{\mathbb C}(t)}\big/{\mathbb C}(t)\bigr)$
on the group $E[p]$-action on $p$-torsion points $E[p]$ of such putative elliptic curve
$E / {\mathbb C}(t)$ that has good reduction at all $t \neq 0, \infty$.
What I not understand is the following statement:

[...]On the other hand, once $p$ exceeds the order of a pole of the $j$-invariant
$j_E^{\phantom.}$, the image of Galois includes
a $p$-cycle ramified above that pole.  [...]

Why that's the case? Could somebody elaborate this argument on precise connection of pole orders of $j_E$ at certain points and existence of such $p$-cycle in the image under the induced $G \to \text{Aut}_{\mathbb C(t)}(E[p])$ & its ramification behavior with details?
The flavour of the statement reminds me loosely on Neron-Ogg's, but here the $j$-invariant is not integral due to presence of poles, so I not know which result is here going to be invoked.
Going a step back, what does it mean that mean that a $p$-cycle (...more generally a subgroup) inside the Aut group ramifies about some point/prime ideal? I know what it means to be "(un)ramified" as Galois representation, or as a morphism of schemes, but what does it mean that a $p$- cycle (or a subgroup) inside Aut group ramifies as stated above?
Or does Elkies consider here $ \text{Aut}_{\mathbb C(t)}(E[p])$ & resp its subgroups "en passant" as schemes over $\Bbb C[t]$ interpreting the discussed $p$-cycle to ramified over a prime/ point in this sense?
And if that's the case, how it this related to the poles of $j$- function? The way Noam Elkies stated this, suggests that there is a for specialists a well known "big" result relating poles of $j$-function with ramification behavior of subfields of the $p$-torsion field extension, from which the quoted claim follows immediately. But which is it?

Let me expand that sentence, which may hint at the confusion in this and the subsequent question.
Let $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ and see the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[t]$ as a Dedekind ring. Let $v$ be a place of $R$ such that the $j$-invariant has a pole at $v$. Suppose $p$ is a prime such that $p>-v(j)$.
For a place $w$ in $L=K\bigl(E[p]\bigr)$ above $v$, there is the decomposition group $D_{w/v}$ inside the Galois group of $L/K$. The curve $E$ over the completion $K_v$ has multiplicative reduction and the curve is isomorphic to a Tate curve $E(L_w) \cong L_w^{\times}/q^{\mathbb{Z}}$ for $q=\tfrac{1}{j}+\cdots\in K_w$ of valuation $-v(j)$. The $p$-torsion points are generated by a primitive $p$-th root of unity $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}^\times \subset L_w^{\times}$ and a $p$-th root of $q$. Since $p>v(q)$, this prime $p$ cannot divide $v(q)$ and hence $L_w$ is simply $K_v\bigl(\sqrt[p]{q}\bigr)$ which is a degree $p$ extension and $D_{w/v}$ is cyclic of order $p$. In terms of the Galois representation, the image of $D_{w/v}$ in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. That is your element of order $p$. The extension is clearly totally ramified, i.e. $D_{w/v} = I_{w/v}$ is the inertia group.
I recommend appendix A.1 in Serre's "Abelian $\ell$-adic representations and elliptic curve" and Silverman II. There $K$ is a number field and $K_v$ is a $p$-adic field, the above works just as well here.

just to check if I understood the logic of the argumentation (even though this might be a triviality): Isn't $L_w$ by construction already $K_v\bigl(\sqrt[p]{q}\bigr)$ independently of additional condition $p >v(q)$? Or does the latter condition only serve to assure that that the extension is non trivial?

Sure, but if $p$ divides $v(q)$, we could have that $q$ is a $p$-th power in $K_v$ in which case $K_v=L_w$ is a trivial extension. The important part is that the extension is non-trivial of degree $p$.
